# MATLAB Correlation fails 'number of rows'

Tags: matlab, correlation

I am attempting a correlation analysis of a matrix `X` `1000x60x5` by a vector `Y` `1000x1`. Using the code:

```
for g=1:size(X,1)
    for h=1:size(X,2)
        C = corr(X(g,h,:),Y,'rows','complete','Type','Spearman');
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error:

```
??? Error using ==> corr at 103
X and Y must have the same number of rows.
```

Despite the fact that they do both have 1000 rows. I can't figure out why this is.

Comment: What's your goal here? You're overwriting `C` at every loop iteration... what correlation or set of correlations are you after exactly?

Comment: I'm going to ask a new question. I thought I knew what I was doing, turns out I don't.

Answer (score 4):

`X` and `Y` don't have the same number of rows, in your case `X` is actually `X(g,h,:)` which has only 5 elements (and only 1 row really) since `g` is a scalar

Comment: +1: The OP is probably wants to find the correlation between `X(:, g, h)` and `Y`, where `g` runs from 1 to `size(X, 2)` and `h` runs from 1 to `size(X, 3)`...